# Product.findByIdAndUpdate is not a function

Tags: mongodb-query, json.net

This is my the code I'm using

```
product = await product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req.body,{
 New:true, 
 runValidators:true, 
 useFindAndModify:false
}) ;
```

But then when I try to test run it with postman I'm being told FindByIdAndUpdate is not a function

Comment: Is product a mongoose model ?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you was a

```js
const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)
```

and You need to change const to let

```js
let product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)
```